# In Sonoma, how can I run applications in /System/Applications from the command line?

Tags: command-line, script, mission-control, sonoma

I have a shell script I sometimes use to trigger Mission Control, which is simply the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
/System/Applications/Mission\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission\ Control
```

In macOS 13, this works fine.

In macOS 14, it crashes with the following:

```
Killed: 9
```

It appears that running any application in /System/Applications is now restricted in macOS Sonoma, unless SIP is disabled.

Is there a way around this without disabling SIP?

Comment: Could you give us some background to this, why you need a script to call Mission Control? You don't need a script to launch Mission Control ordinarily, it's key commandable from anywhere in macOS, I think Ctrl/ ↑ is default.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's partly because sometimes I write scripts to trigger system functions like Mission Control that I can have a third party app run. But I'm the author of an app that can be configured to trigger Mission Control, app exposé, and "show desktop". I need a way to do it that works across all installations of macOS. Using keystrokes is unreliable because the user can change or disable them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
#!/bin/sh
open -a "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control"
```

Comment: That does indeed work around the issue. Any reason why you're using `-a` instead of `open "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app"`?

Comment: @BriBri `open foo` opens the file foo in its default app, `open -a foo` opens the application foo (`open -a foo bar` would open the file bar in the application foo). Check `man open` for details.

Comment: Can't you leave out the full path when you use `-a`, i.e. just `open -a "Mission Control"`

Comment: I ask because `-a` seems unnecessary since we're not telling `open` to open a URL or a document but an application. As far as I know there's only one way to do that: launching it. I'm also confused why `-a "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control"` works given it's pointing to the binary in the app bundle rather than saying which app to open it with. The manpage doesn't make this usage of `-a` clear to me at all! Nonetheless, I'm not disputing that it works.

Comment: I used the whole path so my script would emulate the OP's as closely as possible. As for the -a, I have several aliases in my .zprofile, such as ```alias gc='open -a GraphicConverter\ 12.app'```, and I will admit to a bit of copy-pasta: it worked whenever I first did it, so I kept using it. @nohillside's pointers have me curious now - I always learn from their posts.

Comment: `open /path/to/foo` is the same as double-clicking `foo`, this obviously also works with applications. `open -a Foo.app` uses the application register to launch Foo.app (no path required for standard applications). So, `open -a "Mission Control"` launches Mission Control, no need to add the path for this.

Comment: I'll add on to this answer to say that you can trigger "app expose" and "show desktop" with `open "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app" --args 1` and `open "/System/Applications/Mission Control.app" --args 2`

Answer (score 10):

You already got a workaround, but the cause for this is Apple's ["launch constraints"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/applying_launch_environment_and_library_constraints?language=objc). You can see this if you open Console.app and filter for `AMFI` while trying to spawn the binary in question:

> AMFI: Launch Constraint Violation (enforcing), error info: c[1]p[1]m[1]e[14], (Constraint not matched) launching proc[vc: 1 pid: 10286]: /System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control, launch type 0, failure proc [vc: 1 pid: 10286]: /System/Applications/Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission Control

Apple documents some of the values that can show up in this log message, but in the specific case of `c[1]p[1]m[1]e[14]`, all relevant info is essentially "reserved by the operating system".

But in general, this is a mitigation introduced by Apple to enforce that non-interactive system binaries can only be launched in ways that they expect, because there have been multiple security vulnerabilities in macOS that were based on running system binaries from paths they didn't expect, under a parent process from which they inherited certain properties, etc.