# Does Apple publish a list of new security features and restrictions in macOS?

Tags: macos, security

Earlier today I discovered a [feature in my software wasn't working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/468019/in-sonoma-its-no-longer-possible-to-run-applications-in-system-applications-f) because Apple introduced a new restriction to macOS Sonoma that prevents shells from launching any executable within /System/Applications. I saw no mention of this restriction in their Sonoma release notes.

Does Apple publish any sort of document that lists these sorts of changes to macOS so that developers can be aware of them and properly adapt their software?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is No. But....

Overall guide is the [Apple Platform Security Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/security/welcome/web) - the PDF linked at the bottom is as complete as it gets.

For a developer the starting point is [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com).

Here are [macOS Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/).

[Apple Security Releases](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201222) is the starting point for security fixes in every release of every Apple OS. These often seem to have unexpected (and possibly unintended) consequences.

The [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/) is where Apple presents new features to developers. Some of this is security related - more in some years than others.

On the specific issue of launching apps from  `/System/Applications` you already have answers in your other question [In Sonoma, it's no longer possible to run applications in /System/Applications from the command line or a shell script. Any idea why?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/468019/in-sonoma-its-no-longer-possible-to-run-applications-in-system-applications-f?noredirect=1&lq=1).